# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}})^n}{n\mathrm{!}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Test the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}})^n}{n\mathrm{!}}$$
Thanks!

Comment: What tests have you tried? What can you say about the numerator?

Comment: I have tried cauchy root test, it gives no conclusion.

Comment: You will find the [Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) approximation to the factorial works very nicely. One could get away with somewhat less.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observe that by Stirling's approximation we always have
$$n!\le e\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
and so we see that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(1+\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{n!}\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{e\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\infty$$
thus the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)\leq \left(1+\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)$$
And so we have$$\frac{{\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)}^n}{n\mathrm !}\leq \frac{{\left(1+\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)}^n}{n\mathrm !}$$
Now the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)}^n}{n\mathrm !}$ is divergent by logarithmic test. So the given series is divergent.

Comment: I think doing in this way would be much easier.

Comment: Why are you asking this question if you already have a solution? -2.

Comment: I have found it by seeing the previous answer. To be more precise by seeing 2nd step of it.